# Error Message When Running python ez_setup.py in mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Complete newbie to programming. 
I'm getting this when I try running python ez_setup.py in my mac terminal.

Abbys-iMac:Desktop abbyhumphreys$ python ez_setup.py
Extracting in /var/folders/4h/g2tg60bs1qj041hfpmrf5k7r0000gn/T/tmpyWDENo
Now working in /var/folders/4h/g2tg60bs1qj041hfpmrf5k7r0000gn/T/tmpyWDENo/setuptools-14.3.1
Installing Setuptools
running install
Checking .pth file support in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-47808.pth'
```

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
Abbys-iMac:Desktop abbyhumphreys$

Eek, have no idea what this means or how to go about it. May be in above my head.

Would love to know your opinion on how to resolve this problem.

Thank you :)

Thanks for the anwers

Comment: I think you should read the error message first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need root access to install into that directory.

You can get that by prepeding `sudo` to your command. Try

```
sudo python ez_setup.py
```

Comment: And thank you for the quick answer! Sorry if it sounded like a silly question! :)

Comment: Of course, i still have another minute to go before i can! But will do as soon as.